# Существует ли фрейворк\конструктор для ИИ (работа с видео)?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Например, задача, обучить ИИ определять типы коробок: квадрат, прямоугольник, тубус.
Из видео потока.

Загрузить ведоряд, дать задачу отыскать какой формы коробка.

Ссылки на гитхаб приветствуются.
Любые материалы по теме, ссылки на фреймворки (догадываюсь что есть такие).

Comment: Да, конечно такие существует. Можете посмотреть EmguCV подойдёт для разных языков(сам писал на C#, вполне приятно), метод распознавания может быть разный, смотря что распознавать. Если как вы написали коробки, то вот например:  https://proglib.io/p/real-time-object-detection/#framecode Тут реализация на python, можно привести ещё кучу примеров, также можно посмотреть библиотеку OpenCV, опять же под python хорошо

Comment: спасибо, обязательно пригодится

Comment: Также вот тут, очень интересно написано, на счёт распознования геометрических фигур (я как понял Вам и нужно это :) https://cutt.ly/feIxzQP

Comment: @ПростоКодер, вот эта ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv